# Is there a way to call a public int from another class?

Tags: java, int, public

Is there a way to use a non static public int in another class?

I want to have classes where I have useful functions and static information that I use in many other classes in different packages.

```
info.longrandom
```

Does not work because it is non static.

```
package common.info

public class info {
public int veryshortrandom = (int)(Math.random() * 500 + 1001);
public int shortrandom = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 2001);
public int mediumrandom = (int)(Math.random() * 1500 + 3001);
public int longrandom = (int)(Math.random() * 3000 + 6001);
public int verylongrandom = (int)(Math.random() * 6000 + 1201);
}
```

I am hoping for something that would be akin to:

```
return info.longrandom
```

Comment: First you have to create object of `info` class and then access it's members - if you do not want to use `static`.

Comment: If its not static you can call it from another class, but using an instance of `info`

Comment: `return new info().longrandom;` should work. Returns a new value every time too

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it does, but making it `static` here makes much more sense.

Comment: Thankyou XtremeBaumer, that will work fine for me.

Comment: Why would you even want a class containing a bunch of non-static constants? That would require instantiating it over and over again just to read those constants. It is poor desing and a clear anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access member of a class using the class name in only of the member is static. As static members are declared in a global memory unlike non-static member which exists locally in that class only. Or else you always need to create instance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be needing to make a Getter. There are two ways of doing so:
Creating a new instance of the class by doing 
1:

```
Info info = new Info();
```

And then getting the int by doing:

```
int i = info.veryshortrandom;
```

or

```
return info.veryshortrandom;
```

2.
Making it static :|

Best of luck!
- Thibaut

Answer (score 0):

Non-static attribures are bound to instanses. How can you obtain it without creating an instance?!

Answer (score 0):

return new info().longrandom;

– XtremeBaumer